How to filter additional data after grouping with collapse or aggs syntax in Elasticsearch
I am researching a way to filter data after grouping. For example, here is the data:
index: domain_user_search
doc:
[
{
"domain_key": "PElvL8li",
"delete_yn": "Y",
"@timestamp": "2024-12-03T05:49:51.000Z"
},
{
"domain_key": "3zit1iG4",
"delete_yn": "N",
"@timestamp": "2024-12-03T05:47:56.000Z"
},
{
"domain_key": "MPfyjQrP",
"delete_yn": "N",
"@timestamp": "2024-12-03T05:47:56.000Z"
},
{
"domain_key": "vBYwrqvO",
"delete_yn": "N",
"@timestamp": "2024-12-03T05:46:56.000Z"
},
{
"domain_key": "PElvL8li",
"delete_yn": "N",
"@timestamp": "2024-12-03T05:45:51.000Z"
},
]

Data like this exists,
GET /domain_user_mapping/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_domain_key": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "domain_key.keyword",
        "size": 3
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest_doc": {
          "filter": {
            "match_all": {}
          },
          "aggs": {
            "sorted_docs": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "@timestamp",
                "size": 1,
                "order": {
                  "_key": "desc"
                }
              },
              "aggs": {
                "filtered_doc_content": {
                  "filter": {
                    "term": {
                      "delete_yn.keyword": "N"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

If you search with a query like this:
"aggregations": {
    "group_by_domain_key": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 3,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "PElvL8li",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "latest_doc": {
            "doc_count": 2,
            "sorted_docs": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 1,
              "buckets": [
                {
                  "key": 1733204991000,
                  "key_as_string": "2024-12-03T05:49:51.000Z",
                  "doc_count": 1,
                  "filtered_doc_content": {
                    "doc_count": 0
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "3zit1iG4",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "latest_doc": {
            "doc_count": 1,
            "sorted_docs": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": [
                {
                  "key": 1733204876000,
                  "key_as_string": "2024-12-03T05:47:56.000Z",
                  "doc_count": 1,
                  "filtered_doc_content": {
                    "doc_count": 1
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "MPfyjQrP",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "latest_doc": {
            "doc_count": 1,
            "sorted_docs": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": [
                {
                  "key": 1733204876000,
                  "key_as_string": "2024-12-03T05:47:56.000Z",
                  "doc_count": 1,
                  "filtered_doc_content": {
                    "doc_count": 1
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }

As the key is PElvL8li, the data whose delete_yn is Y is the most recent, so the data is included and "PElvL8li","3zit1iG4","MPfyjQrP" is displayed.
What I want is that since delete_yn is Y, it is excluded from the response data and I want to receive 3 data, "3zit1iG4","MPfyjQrP","vBYwrqvO".
The prerequisite is that the data whose delete_yn is Y should be removed in advance and grouped based on the latest time, and the data whose delete_yn is Y should be excluded after grouping based on the latest time.
Is this filtering possible with a query?
